# type of the neural network

Tags: neural-networks, keras

I am developing a neural network for a binary classification task. I am using the following code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(200, input_shape=(9,), kernel_regularizer=l2(0.1), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(80, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(40, activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
# lr was 0.0001
# optimizer was RMS prop
model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.01), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Is this considered an MLP, feed forwards, or what exactly is its name ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using stacks of `dense` layers. These are called fully connected network(FCN) because all the nodes in the layers are connected to each other rather than kernelized operations. In the case of binary classification, the last layer should have only one node. And the outputs will be probabilistic values(0~1) either the input is 100% dog or 80% dog or so.